# Bitlocker on Windows partition, windows dead after Ubuntu install

Tags: mount, windows

My company laptop came with bitlocker and Windows 10

During the Ubuntu installation it invited me to deactivate bitlocker which I did. I used gparted to resize my windows partition which I think as a mistake. I should have used windows to do the resizing of the bitlocker partition?

Posting this from Ubuntu 22.04. I can't boot windows. It asks me for my bitlocker recovery password. No clue what that is and would prefer to avoid asking corporate.

I also can't mount my windows partition to recover the one file I really need:

```
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p3 ~/win
mount: /home/francis/win: unknown filesystem type 'BitLocker'.
```

I installed dislocker

```
sudo dislocker -r -V /dev/nvme0n1p3 -u -- /media/mount 
Mon Oct  3 10:25:01 2022 [CRITICAL] Cannot parse volume header. Abort.
```

Comment: You need to ask the Corporate people for the bitlocker info. You could try on the Windows support site to see if there is another way to deal with the Bitlocker issue. https://superuser.com/

Comment: This ^^^ The correct procedure, assuming you're even allowed to install a dual-boot, is to disable Bitlocker, backup the password, shrink the Windows system partition, and only then boot the Ubuntu installer.

Comment: >  shrink the Windows system partition, and only then boot the Ubuntu installer.... I think you meant reestablish bitlocker before going to Ubuntu. I think that's where everything went wrong.